# Using nearest neighbour interpolation for flutter image

Tags: flutter

How do I get flutter to resize my `Image` widgets using nearest neighbour interpolation if the size of the widget is not the same as the asset size?

```
class PlayContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 110, 255),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Image(
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          image: AssetImage("assets/knight.png")
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This resizes the image correctly, but it is blurry due to the bilinear interpolation used to resize it.

Based on the [source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/23499f400422153cdf6ee8c34046bd0dd0f13d48/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/decoration_image.dart#L413) seems to be rather hard coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible in the master branch thanks to this [Pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23329):

> I've added the possibility to set the filterQuality on Images. This was hardcoded.
> The previously hardcoded value is set as default parameter.
>
> Some images look better when scaled with no filter quality (like pixelart). That's why I added the parameter.